# Javascript asynchronous Function Call : Retrieve calling function paramters in callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I get the user state in Javascript callback function ? Like I have a Javascript funciton making an asynchronous call as follows. Now In callback function I need to access userstate. How can I do this? In Silverlight we have userstate kind of thing. Do we have same kind of mechanism in Javascript as well. Please assist.

Note: I dont want to make use of Global variable as Func1() will be executed in a For Loop.

```
   function Func1() {
       var userState = "someValue";
       geocoder.asyncCall(parameters , CallBack);
   }


   function CallBack(result) {

       // Use result
       // How to access userState in this function
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function Func1() {
   var userState = "someValue";
   geocoder.asyncCall(parameters ,function(){ 
      CallBack(userState);
   });
}


function CallBack(result) {

   // Use result
   // How to access userState in this function
}
```

**update**

```
function PlotAddressOnMap(address) { 
   var address = address; 
   var userState="userState";
   geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, CityDetailsReceived(userState)); 
} 

function CityDetailsReceived(userState) {
   return function(results, status){
      //your code
   }
}
```

Comment: Though I am getting the userState but I am not getting the expected result now. Actually I am using Google API as follows:


       // Function to get state details using Google Geocoder
       function PlotAddressOnMap(address) {
           var address = address;
           var userState="userState";
           geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, CallBack(userState));
       }

  function CityDetailsReceived(userState , results, status ) {
         }

Though I am able to get userState now , but I am not getting the expected result in results and status variables.

Answer (score 4):

```
function Func1() {
   var userState = "someValue";
   geocoder.asyncCall(parameters , CallBack(userState));
}


function CallBack(userState) {
   return function(result){
       // userState is accessible
   }
}
```

Comment: Though I am getting the userState but I am not getting the expected result now. Actually I am using Google API as follows:


       // Function to get state details using Google Geocoder
       function PlotAddressOnMap(address) {
           var address = address;
           var userState="userState";
           geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, CallBack(userState));
       }

  function CityDetailsReceived(userState , results, status ) {
         }

Though I am able to get userState now , but I am not getting the expected result in results and status variables.